# Proving Scaled Random Walk Approaches Normal Distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, random-walk, proof

I'm reading Stochastic Calculus for Finance II: Continuous-Time Models by Steven Shreve and I don't understand how he went from the equation on the left to the middle one. If it helps, this section is proving that the distribution of a scaled random walk converges to the normal distribution.

[image]

Comment: isn't that becuase X is either +1 or -1 with 50% probability, so the step you are highlighting is the discrete expectation of these two outcomes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X_j$ can be either 1 or -1 with 50% probability each. So this step is just applying the expectation to both possible cases.

See [definition of the Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case)...
\begin{align}
{\mathbb E}\bigl[ X \bigr] = \sum_i i \cdot p(x = i)
\end{align}

It's the sum over all possibilities of the probability of getting that value (both ${\frac 1 2}$ in your case) multiplied by the value